# angular CLI 11 version is not working in Internet explorer 11

Tags: angular, browser, internet-explorer-11, polyfills, angular11

Angular CLI 11 not working in IE 11
I have used
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I assume that you have created a new **Angular CLI 11** empty project that you want to run in the IE 11 browser.

I suggest you refer to the steps below that may help you to run the Angular CLI 11 project in the IE 11 browser.

1. Open the `tsconfig.json` file and set `"target": "es5"`.
2. Open the `.browserslistrc` file and remove the `not` prefix before `IE 11`. It should look like below.

[image]

Other than that no changes required in the newly created Angular CLI 11 project to run it with the IE 11 browser.

Further, you can add the necessary polyfills as per the requirement.

Output in the IE 11:

[image]

Comment: hi need one more help..... Trying to redirecting to External URL but URL should be hidden or dummy URL should be in address bar I have used window.location.href = URL; this is working but URL is visible . Is this possible??
Or any option to hide url when request for specific api..
angular

Comment: We can see that your new question is not related to the topic of the original thread. I suggest you create a new thread for a new issue. Thanks for your understanding