# Angular9 upgrade to Angular11 IE11 issue

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, angular11, angular-upgrade

We are trying to upgrade our `angular 9.0.4` application to `angular 11.2.7`. In the previous version the application worked fine in `IE11` but after the upgrade it does not works anymore (nothing shown nothing logged).

Any help or hint would be appreciated...

I have found many instruction to make it work in case of new applications like:
https://dev.to/coly010/angular-how-to-support-ie11-4924 or [angular CLI 11 version is not working in Internet explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242735/angular-cli-11-version-is-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11) but none of them worked so far for upgrade

I double checked our `polyfills.ts` and everything looks fine.
The only thing what I could not find is the `.browserlist` file.
Based on this post: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18032 it seems that the `IE11` support became an opt-in feature so I created a file called `.browserlist` (and I tried with the file name `.browserlistrc`) the content:

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major version
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 9-10
IE 11
```

Still not works...
If I run the command: `npx browserslist` I get back the supported list including IE

```
chrome 90
edge 90
edge 89
firefox 87
firefox 78
ie 11
ios_saf 14.0-14.5
ios_saf 13.4-13.7
ios_saf 13.3
ios_saf 13.2
ios_saf 13.0-13.1
safari 14
safari 13.1
```

Here are some of the settings in case you can spot something what I missed:

The build target is set to es5 in our `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "build/www/app",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/main/webapp/app",
    "src/test/javascript/"
  ],
  "exclude": [
  ]
}
```

Here is the content of our `polyfills.ts`:

```
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
import 'core-js/es/promise';

import 'eligrey-classlist-js-polyfill';  // Run `npm install --save eligrey-classlist-js-polyfill`.

import 'core-js/es/reflect';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.

// IE 11 does not support matches only webkitMatchesSelector
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
    Element.prototype.matches = (<any>Element.prototype).msMatchesSelector ||
        Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
}

require('../manifest.webapp');
```

Right now the plan is to start a brand new application and add the IE11 support there and try to apply those changes to the existing application but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In my new Angular 11 app, I didn't uncomment the polyfills in `polyfills.ts`. In my `polyfills.ts`, there's only this line `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` uncommented. As far as I know, Angular 8+ doesn't need to uncomment `polyfills.ts` to make it compatible with IE. You can try to restore the `polyfills.ts` to its original state to see what happens.

Comment: I tried it and indeed it worked for the new application what I made but it did not worked for the application what I have to upgrade...
Are you using `webpack` to build the app?

Comment: No, I didn't use `webpack`. In your situation, I think it's hard to locate the issue as no error logs. You can migrate the original code into a new Angular 11 app as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you! Migrating is not an option since we don't want to lose all the history. We generated the project skeleton 2017 with angular 4... It seems that the build process changed a loot since then and while we upgraded the dependencies we did not touched the build itself. Right now we wait and see if the management says OK to get rid of IE11 support. If they say no we try to adapt the build process and post the solution if it is done.

Comment: That sounds good. You can come back if you make any progress or have any further issues.